# Types are the same but needs explicit conversion?

Tags: c#, arrays, types

I have a table where an image is uploaded as an bytes array, or byte[0] if the user doesn't provide one.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", string.IsNullOrEmpty(updateObj.image) ? new byte[0] : Convert.FromBase64String(updateObj.image.Split(',').Last()));
```

However when I pull the data back out, it says that the type is 'object' even though a `.GetType()` returns `System.Byte[]`.

Here's the kind of error I'm getting:

```
byte[] b = new byte[0];
Console.WriteLine("reader[pic] type is " + reader["pic"].GetType());
Console.WriteLine("b type is " + b.GetType());
```

shows as:

```
reader[pic] type is System.Byte[]
b type is System.Byte[]
```

but trying:

`b = reader["pic"]`

shows:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'byte[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Here are images if they help.
[image: Cannot implicitly convert type]
[image: console]

Explicitly type casting it works but I would like to know why this happens.

Comment: Please post text instead of pictures

Comment: Sorry, thought it'd make more sense to see visually where and what the error shows and the pictures themselves aren't necessary to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your confusion, but a 5 minutes' read (They say so :)) can reveal a very basic concept of object-oriented programming: Boxing & Unboxing:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

And also check what wikipedia has to say on the same concept:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)

What happens in your case is, the byte array (the actual value of the "pic" column) is handed to you wrapped in a box (an object instance).

Therefore; You have to unbox it to get the byte array.

```
        byte[] b = new byte[0];

        Console.WriteLine("reader[pic] type is " + reader["pic"].GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("b type is " + b.GetType());

        b = (byte[])reader["pic"];

        // or, for reference types:

        b = reader["pic"] as byte[];
```

And why are you getting it wrapped in a box?

Because as you can get a byte[] from your reader (possibly one of IDataReader implementations, like SqlDataReader) by accessing its indexer, you can also get an integer, a string, or any type that is supported by the SqlDbType enumeration.

```
        // for value types, an explicit cast is required
        int customerAge = (int)reader["age"];
```

Comment: Thank you I wasn't quite sure what the terms to search for was and I did try to look. Do you know why `.GetType()` is returning the unboxed type? If I'm reading this right article: http://tooslowexception.com/how-does-gettype-work/ , `GetType()` uses a pointer to the object itself and that's why it returns `System.Byte[]`?

Comment: You're welcome. As pointed out in another stackoverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447315/boxing-and-unboxing-why-arent-the-outputs-both-system-object), you can check the image which explains this, at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#boxing

Comment: The answer is yes by the way. :)

Answer (score 3):

It does that because `object` is the return type of the indexer of SqlDataReader

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.item?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_Item_System_Int32_

```cs
public override object this[string name] { get; }
```